# Access management web console from external address

Tags: console, remote-access, activemq-artemis

Accessing the management console with http://localhost:8161/console and http://127.0.0.1:8161/console works, but with http://10.0.2.15:8161/console it hangs.

netstat -nlt
tcp6       0      0 :::8161                 :::*                    LISTEN

on bootstrap.xml have:

```
<web bind="http://0.0.0.0:8161" path="web">
```

on jolokia-access.xml I've tried a lot of combos with no luck:

```
<restrict>
    <!-- tried with and without
    <cors> 
        <allow-origin>*://10.0.2.15*</allow-origin>
        <allow-origin>*://10.0.2.15:8161</allow-origin>
        <allow-origin>*://*</allow-origin>
        <strict-checking/>
    </cors> 
    -->
</restrict>
```

I'm running it inside virtualbox on a xubuntu VM. What am I missing here?

telnet 10.0.2.15 8161:

```
Trying 10.0.2.15...
Connected to 10.0.2.15.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /console
HTTP/1.1 400 HTTP/0.9 not supported
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 65
Connection: close

<h1>Bad Message 400</h1><pre>reason: HTTP/0.9 not supported</pre>Connection closed by foreign host.
```

telnet 10.0.2.15 8161

```
Trying 10.0.2.15...
Connected to 10.0.2.15.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /console HTTP/1.0
HANGS
```

Comment: So it's working fine when you access the web console locally from within the xubuntu VM, but when you try to access it from outside the xubuntu VM it fails?

Comment: No...even inside xubuntu fails. From the host machine with NAT (and port fowarding) I also can access to  http://localhost:8161/console and http://127.0.0.1:8161/console.

Comment: I just tried using telnet and it hangs for me as well, but I can still access the web console with a browser.  Therefore, I'm not sure telnet provides a reliable indication of whether or not the console is actually accessible.

Comment: browser and curl hangs for me as well. $ curl -i http://10.0.2.15:8161/console ....and stays here

Comment: when I connect from the host machine I get a timeout from browser. What do you have in jolokia-access.xml? Is there anything else that can be blocking the request? Can I add some debug logging level that can help?

Comment: Found it....I was driving crazy. Thanks Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After issuing

```
curl -v http://10.0.2.15:8161/console/ -H "Host: localhost:8161"
 Trying 10.0.2.15...
 TCP_NODELAY set
 Connected to 10.0.2.15 (10.0.2.15) port 9999 (#0)
 GET http://10.0.2.15:8161/console/ HTTP/1.1
 Host: localhost:8161
```

found out that it was my local proxy running on 9999 that was causing the issue.